# What is the name of the book about Reincarnation (Gilgul) written by one of the Arizal students

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, arizal

The book consists about relating different lifes in the Torah. E.g: the couple Yossef and the Pharao's wife and Yoshua and Rachav are the same souls.
The author is one of the Arizal's students.

Answer (score 4):

I think you’re looking for Sha’ar HaGilgulim of Rav Chaim Vital.

See Wikipedia [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaar_HaGilgulim).