# PTIJ: I need a rolling gate

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I am looking for a rolling gate. All of my *life* I’ve maintained that it is *vital* I find it. It has been pointed out that a lion wrote on the rolling gate, a lion with great zeal indeed wrote on the rolling gate, the lion’s vitals were stellar by the way, which is why it lived by the rolling gate.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120197/what-is-the-name-of-the-book-about-reincarnation-gilgul-written-by-one-of-the

Comment: @sabbahillel My comment was also not serious

Answer (score 0):

See

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A3_%D7%9C%D7%90_%D7%90

> אימתי הוא נעילה רבנן דקיסרין אמרין איתפלגון רב ור' יוחנן רב אמר בנעילת
> שערי שמים ור"י אמר בנעילת שערי היכל

Also

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%91%D7%97%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93_%D7%98

> ההיכל היה בניינו רחב מלפניו וצר מאחוריו כמו ארי

*Dok ve'tishkach*.

PS. If the gates aren't rolling, have another *le'chayim*.